# Chaining iterators together to remove repeated code

Tags: rust, iterator, dry

The following code attempts to chain two iterators together.

```
fn main() {
    let height = 3;
    let width = 4;
    let horizontal = (0..height).map(|row| {let rw = row * width; rw..rw + width});
    horizontal.for_each(|x| { print!("("); x.for_each(|x|print!(" {:?} ", x)); println!(")");});
    let vertical = (0..width).map(|col| (0..height).map(move |n| col + n * width));
    vertical.for_each(|x| { print!("("); x.for_each(|x|print!(" {:?} ", x)); println!(")");});
    let all = horizontal.chain(vertical);
    //all.for_each(|x| { print!("("); x.for_each(|x|print!(" {:?} ", x)); println!(")");});
}
```

But the compiler complains about mismatched types.

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Map<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:6:35: 6:82]> as IntoIterator>::Item == std::ops::Range<{integer}>`
 --> src/main.rs:8:26
  |
8 |     let all = horizontal.chain(vertical);
  |                          ^^^^^ expected struct `Map`, found struct `std::ops::Range`
  |
  = note: expected type `Map<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:6:57: 6:81]>`
           found struct `std::ops::Range<{integer}>`
```

The signature of chain is:

```
fn chain<U>(self, other: U) -> Chain<Self, <U as IntoIterator>::IntoIter>ⓘ where
    U: IntoIterator<Item = Self::Item>
```

Both iterators have as Item type an Iterator with the same Item type, which admittedly is not quite what the signature demands. But I can call for example `.for_each(|x| { print!("("); x.for_each(|x|print!(" {:?} ", x)); println!(")");})` on each iterator, so why can't I construct the chain to call it on the chain? Is there another way to remove such code duplication?

Comment: `for_each()` is evil

Comment: @Stargateur Actually, after `chain()`, `for_each()` is preferred (more performant) - but the OP uses it _before_.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I argue it's a bug (but yeah) that why I include the ultra bonus answer that don't use for_each but use collect (could be try_fold) that allow better perf and is actually a good use case. for_each is bad, collect is ok (in my eye)

Comment: @Stargateur I feel like using `map()` and `collect()` to replace `for_each()` is _far_ more evil than just using `for_each()`. It's a nice trick, but `for_each` is there for a reason, and while I can immediately understand what a code with `for_each()` does (even if it's unpleasant to the eye), I'll have to take a second look on your version.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I would like to call chain+for_each once, but I am unable to call chain, and so forced to call for_each twice. Suppose I have many more sequences like horizontal and vertical... this is my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your types doesn't have the same `Item`:

```rust
.map(|row| {let rw = row * width; rw..rw + width});
.map(|col| (0..height).map(move |n| col + n * width))
```

One is a `Range` the other is a `Map` of a `Range`.

The solution is to use `flatten()` or on your case `flat_map()`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let height = 3;
    let width = 4;

    println!("Horizontal:");
    let horizontal = (0..height).flat_map(|row| {
        let rw = row * width;
        rw..rw + width
    });
    for x in horizontal.clone() {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }

    println!("\nVertical:");
    let vertical = (0..width).flat_map(|col| (0..height).map(move |n| col + n * width));
    for x in vertical.clone() {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }

    println!("\nAll:");
    let all = horizontal.chain(vertical);
    for x in all {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

This made both `vertical` and `horizontal` iterator have the same `Item` type. Also, I remove `for_each()` in my opinion it's make the code unclear as for loop are for side effect that is imperative paradigm and iterator chaining is functional paradigm.

---

Bonus:

```rust
fn print_my_iter(name: &str, iter: impl Iterator<Item = i32>) {
    println!("{}:", name);
    for x in iter {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let height = 3;
    let width = 4;

    let horizontal = (0..height).flat_map(|row| {
        let rw = row * width;
        rw..rw + width
    });
    print_my_iter("Horizontal", horizontal.clone());

    let vertical = (0..width).flat_map(|col| (0..height).map(move |n| col + n * width));
    print_my_iter("\nVertical", vertical.clone());

    let all = horizontal.chain(vertical);
    print_my_iter("\nAll", all);
}
```

---

Ultra bonus:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn print_my_iter(name: &str, iter: impl Iterator<Item = i32>) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut handle = stdout.lock();

    writeln!(handle, "{}:", name)?;
    iter.map(|x| writeln!(handle, "{:?}", x)).collect()
}

fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let height = 3;
    let width = 4;

    let horizontal = (0..height).flat_map(|row| {
        let rw = row * width;
        rw..rw + width
    });
    print_my_iter("Horizontal", horizontal.clone())?;

    let vertical = (0..width).flat_map(|col| (0..height).map(move |n| col + n * width));
    print_my_iter("\nVertical", vertical.clone())?;

    let all = horizontal.chain(vertical);
    print_my_iter("\nAll", all)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: IIUC If I use flatmap, then the sequence of sequences is flattened into a big sequence. For printing just the elements that makes little difference, but the subsequence are essential, so suppose I add parens in my print function (which I will edit in shortly).